# WPF View Styles Referenced By SystemResourceKey

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I'm trying to replicate the `Style` of `DataGridComboBoxColumn's` `TextBlockComboBox`. This is the control used by the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` when the column's cells are not being edited. I was able to find out about this control by viewing the source at [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) (I would attempt to link directly to the type in question, but the browser on my work laptop has a security plugin that mangles URLs). Here is a snippet from that source:

```
    internal class TextBlockComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        static TextBlockComboBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlockComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DataGridComboBoxColumn.TextBlockComboBoxStyleKey));
            KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStopProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlockComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Style key for TextBlockComboBox
    /// </summary>
    public static ComponentResourceKey TextBlockComboBoxStyleKey
    {
        get
        {
            return SystemResourceKey.DataGridComboBoxColumnTextBlockComboBoxStyleKey;
        }
    }
```

From this snippet, you can see that the `Style` for this control has it's key defined in `SystemResourceKey.DataGridComboBoxColumnTextBlockComboBoxStyleKey`. I would like to copy this `Style` in order to make additions and modifications in my own codebase. I can't seem to find the `Style` that this key referes to, however. I tried duplicating the control (since it is an internal type) and using the Visual Studio Designer's Edit Template feature to get a generated copy of the `Style/Template`, but all I got was the default `ComboBox` `Template`. From there, I tried simply using this default `ComboBox` `Style` and trying to modify it until it resembled the `Style` of the `TextBlockComboBox`, but that's just causing problems.

Does anybody know how to determine what is defined in the `Style` for the key `SystemResourceKey.DataGridComboBoxColumnTextBlockComboBoxStyleKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it's defined in `PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll` on Windows 8 and later:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static DataGridComboBoxColumn.TextBlockComboBoxStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="1,1,1,1" Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Awesome! How did you know find it? Aero2 doesn't appear to be included in the .Net source. I see that Aero2 does appear on GitHub. Is this just a matter of knowing that other Windows UI Libraries exist and checking there for cases like this?